# built-in objects marked as illegal in Azure Portal server script editor

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

We were using Azure mobile services for quite some time. And we were using javascript editor integrated in Azure portal quite often. Very handy tool by the way.

Recently it started marking built-in objects like `tables`, `mssql`, `process`, etc. with red markers saying `Could not find symbol 'tables'.`. It was not like this before.

The scripts themselves work just as fine as before. So this is not a really big problem.

I just wonder, may be there was some recent changes in Azure mobile services which we've missed? may be now we can somehow initialise this objects, using `require` or some other way?

Comment: Dunno.  Tweet @scottgu if you don't get an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The team is aware of this issue and should have it fixed in the near future.  The scripts will continue to work just fine (provided they are in fact valid).  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: That's not a problem at all. I just wanted to know that I did not miss anything. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: This fix has now been deployed.